# Why doesn't this code work?

Tags: entities

I'm more or lees newbie developing with drupal and now, specifically, I'm trying to create one new entity. I've seen the entity_example given in examples for developers and also I have read [this post](http://www.istos.it/blog/drupal-entities/drupal-entities-part-3-programming-hello-drupal-entity) recomended in the Entity API docs.

I have understood the basics things. I have created the table for the entity, I have defined de entity with the hook_entity_info(), the links for manage page and create one item of this new entity, etc. And it seems to be fine because when I add one item, i can see it on the database.

The problem is when I try to load the entity data. First of all, I have register the url in the hook_menu().

```
$items['issue/%gissues_issue'] = array(
'title callback' => 'gissues_issue_title',
'title arguments' => array(1),
'page callback' => 'gissues_issue_view',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access arguments' => array('View Issues'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Also, I have created the permissions in hook_permission() and two functions, as I have read in docs, for loading one item or multiple items. I show the code of that functions:

```
function gissues_issue_load($issue_id = NULL, $reset = FALSE) {
    $issue_ids = (isset($issue_id) ? array($issue_id) : array());
    $issue = gissues_issue_load_multiple($issue_ids, $reset);
    return $issue ? reset($issue) : FALSE;
}

function gissues_issue_load_multiple($issue_ids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE) {
    return entity_load('issue', $issue_ids, $conditions, $reset);
}
```

When I execute the code, I receive this error message:

> Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 173 of /home/user/public_html/formacion/includes/entity.inc).
>   Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2168 of /home/user/public_html/formacion/includes/database/database.inc).

I think the entity_load function is not receiving the correct data. The function needs an array with the IDs and it's receiving an array of array. This is what the dpm shows:

```
  (Array, 1 element)
  0 (Array, 1 element)
    2 (Object) stdClass
      issue_id (String, 1 characters ) 2
      bundle_type (String, 13 characters ) general_issue
      [

    entity data

      ]
      rdf_mapping (Array, 0 elements)
```

So that, I'm quite lost. May be its something simple or maybe not, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong o what i'm forgetting to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Is that the exact code you're using? The bit that makes me suspicious is where you declare `$issue_ids`, but instead of using it you pass `array($issue_id)`. Are you sure you're not passing `array($issue_ids)` there by mistake? That would account for the extra wrapping array

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! Ok, the code was wrong. I have updated the post. The code was not the real because of many changes for testing things over the problem.

I have checked again, but I'm still getting the same error. I have put all the code in a github repo. (Is this the best way to show all the code? I'm not sure about that.)

Anyway, many thanks again. If you or somebody can give me light over this problem I will appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

If your module name is

`gissue_issue`

Then you could have a hook namespace collision with

[`hook_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_load/7)

In which case the `$nodes` parameter is being passed to your load function as well.

Just a possibility to consider.

Comment: That won't make a difference - otherwise `user_load()`, `file_load()`, `entity_load()`, and many others would also be collisions ;) `hook_load()` is only for modules implementing a custom node type

Comment: Thanks Clive, you are indeed correct :) hook_load is only called on the module defining that node type.

Comment: Thanks! :) I have read in hook_menu() doc (section "Auto-Loader Wildcards") that whether you declare an URL like  $items['my-module/%mymodule_abc/edit'] and you request 'mymodule/123/edit' then a "mymodule_abc_load" function will be invoked.


This is why the functions is called gissue_issue_load. I have declared in hook_menu() this "$items['issue/%gissues_issue']"

Comment: @luidmagr, yes that's correct there.